# Assets pipeline issues when upgrading to Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm in the middle of upgrading a very old project to the latest version of rails. So I've read a ton about the changes to the Asset pipeline between rails 3.0 and 3.1, including [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) entire page, and I've followed all the steps in part 9. I've also read quite a few stack exchange questions dealing with what appears to be the same issue as mine. None of these are working though.

In `app/views/layouts/_sidebar.html.erb` I have this html:

```
<img id="admin_img" style="border:none"
src="/images/<%= in_server_menu ?  'expanded' : 'collapsed' %>.gif" />
```

After upgrading, I've changed that `src=` to all of the following:

```
src="<%= image_path(in_server_menu ?  'expanded.gif' : 'collapsed.gif' )%>"
src="/assets/<%= in_server_menu ?  'expanded' : 'collapsed' %>.gif"
src="/assets/images/<%= in_server_menu ?  'expanded' : 'collapsed' %>.gif"
src="assets/<%= in_server_menu ?  'expanded' : 'collapsed' %>.gif"
src="app/assets/images/collapsed.gif"
```

and numerous similar paths, but the image fails to load. The actual HTML output for the first two is

```
src="/assets/collapsed.gif"
```

which APPEARS to be correct, as my file system looks like this:

```
project_folder
  ->app
    ->assets
      ->images
        ->collapsed.gif
```

Firefox shows the default "broken image" thumbnail, though, and image info says it's 0 bytes and cannot be loaded, which makes me think it's not being found. I've restarted the server since making changes, and manually opening the file with Firefox works, so the image isn't broken.

`Rails.application.assets.paths` contains

```
/path/to/the/project/folder/app/assets/images
```

as well as the other assets folders.
I've confirmed that the src tag I am modifying is indeed the broken image I'm looking at, so it's nothing as simple as that.

What else can I do to make this image load? What other troubleshooting steps can I take? I am also having issues with other assets not being loaded yet that I can see when I load a page and watch the server output, but I have not yet tackled those.

Answer (score 0):

try like that:-

```
<%= image_tag (in_server_menu ? "expanded.gif" : "collapsed.gif"), :id => "admin_img", :style => "border:none"  %>
```

Comment: Hmm, it got rid of the broken image thumbnail but is now just showing "Collapsed" alt text.

Comment: when `in_server_menu` will return true then only it will show `expanded.gif`.

Comment: Yes, I know, it's currently false. `collapsed.gif` still isn't loading though.

Comment: check the `file name` of image with extension. There may be `Collapsed.gif` instead of `collapsed.gif`

Comment: Interestingly, the alt text is "Collapsed" with a capital C, and that does not appear anywhere in the project.